# How to marshall POJO to JSON using JETTISON?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, marshalling, jettison

I have done the marshalling of a JaxB java object to Json using JETTISON. But I can not marshall a simple java object (which has no annotations in it) to Json using JETTISON. I know it is possible to do it by using GSON or MOXy or some other providers.

But I like to get clear "Can we do it using JETTISON?"., If we can, How to do it?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Don't waste your time, this is simply not what Jettison was designed to do. Conceivably, it would have been possible to instantiate a `JSONObject` with your POJO and serialize it that way, but there are some issues with its code that make this next to impossible:

1. It requires passing in the names of the fields that will be included in the JSON.
2. It can only process public properties of the supplied object.

Not to mention it cannot handle nesting of any kind. Take a look at this lovely code:

```
Class c = object.getClass();
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
        try {
                String name = names[i];
                Field field = c.getField(name);
                Object value = field.get(object);
                this.put(name, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                /* forget about it */
        }
}
```

Yep, thats the code in the constructor `JSONObject(Object, String[])`. I'm sure you will see the problems with it (raw access to generic objects, can only access public fields, sloppy exception handling). All in all - very bad 'serialization' code.

I know its probably not what you want to hear, but if you want to convert regular Java objects to JSON then you might want to stick with one of the more general-purpose libraries.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB (JSR-222) is configuration by exception and only requires annotations where you need to override the default XML representation (Jettison converts XML StAX events to/from JSON).  Instead of `@XmlRootElement` you can wrap your object in an instance of `JAXBElement`.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-no-annotations-required.html

Comment: Thnks Blaise : If I wrap the object in JAXBElement., It ll be act as JAXB(I think)., but I dont need it. I need to marshall a POJO to JSON as it is. Is it possible??

Comment: @VijayKumar - Jettison can't convert objects to JSON directly.  Since it converts StAX events to/from JSON it can be used with an XML binding tool (JAXB is the standard) to produce JSON from objects.  If this is what your environment is doing the using `JAXBElement` is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Yeah., But sometimes I may need to marshall objects which has @Entity annotation too., In that case it will conflict if I try to wrap it in JAXBElement.

Comment: @VijayKumar - Which library is supplying the `@Entity` annotation?  How many JSON binding frameworks are involved in your use case?

Comment: There should be only one framework that will marshall any java objects without any problems. I have done with GSON and it works well. So I gave try to JETTISON., but still I couldn't get it.